# PointCloud - modify scale on Z axis

Tags: eyeshot

I'm working with Point cloud. I would like display my point cloud with a factor scale in Z direction. Then I increase visually the default. 
I tested transformation "Scale" on my entity but it seems not work :

```
  PointCloud c = new PointCloud(pts.Count,1, PointCloud.natureType.Multicolor);
  c.Vertices = pts.ToArray();
  c.DrawingStyle = PointCloud.drawingStyleType.Points;
  c.Scale(new Point3D(0, 0, 0), 1, 1, 10); // Z => x10

  viewportLayout1.Entities.Add(c);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing

```
viewportLayout1.Invalidate();
```

at the end of that.  So you are scaling it, it just is not rendering it on your screen.  Invalidate forces it to redraw your point cloud.

When in doubt I usually throw both of these after my changes.  Make sure to take them out when not needed as they are expensive calls:

```
        viewportLayout1.Entities.Regen();
        viewportLayout1.Invalidate();
```